# Pass a value from login form to main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login screen and I need to pass username to my main form (for getting permissions etc.). Here is my code:

```
//Login
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
        {
            //Show warning
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text))
        {
            //Show warning
        }

        using (DataTable dt = LookupUser(txtUser.Text)) //Look into SQL data table for username and password
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                //Show warning
            }
            else
            {
                string dbPassword = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["pass"]);
                string appPassword = Encrypt(txtPass.Text);
                if (string.Compare(dbPassword, appPassword) == 0)
                {
                    //I need to pass username value to myForm...
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Show warning
                }
            }
        }

//Program.cs
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        DialogResult result;
        using (var loginForm = new Login())
            result = loginForm.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new myForm());
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to pass value from loginForm to Program.cs and myForm?

Comment: Use a backing variable..

Comment: An easy way to do this is with a public static variable in a separate class.

Comment: @Steve: In the static void Main() I call loginForm.ShowDialog(); and after that if DialogResult == OK, I run my app. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In login form

```
public string UserName {get; private set;}

if (string.Compare(dbPassword, appPassword) == 0)
                {
                    UserName = txtUser.Text;
                    //I need to pass username value to myForm...
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Show warning
                }
```

in main

```
    DialogResult result;
    using (var loginForm = new Login())
        result = loginForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var username = loginForm.UserName;
        Application.Run(new myForm(username));
    }
```

Comment: Still lacks one last step, how to pass the username to the myForm

Comment: I guess myForm can have a constructor that takes username as parameter

Comment: I personnally thing it would be much better for the username to be stored at a session-level class that itself could be accessed from myForm or any other classes. There should be no need for myForm to handle to it.

Comment: @Crono1981 I would agree if I had more details about what he's trying to do. For his question *"best way to pass value from loginForm to Program.cs and myForm"* I think this is sufficient.

Comment: Point taken. :) However, based on previous (and admittedly distant) experience, custom Form constructors may cause issues with the designer. I suggest a property or a set method instead.

Comment: @Crono1981 it wouldn't be a issue if you leave the default constructor intact.

Answer (score 1):

Expose username as a string property of your login form class. This way you'll be able to fetch it after the form will be closed (it will still remain in memory).

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the best way to transfer data from one form to another, On the LoginForm.cs write like this:

   ```
   ex.UserName = txtUserName.text;    
   Password=txtPassword.text;    
   MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(UserName,Password);    
   this.Hide(); 

   mainForm.Show();
   ```
2. In the MainForm.cs edit the

   public MainForm ()
   { 
   }

like this:

```
public MainForm(string userName,string password){
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer would be clearer if you could edit it to separate the code from your narrative.

Answer (score 0):

it is simply use EF on your codes
just like below

```
  }
    Siman_dbEntities db = new Siman_dbEntities();
    public string UserNameLogedIn;
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var login = from b in db.Tbl_Users.Where(b => b.Username == txtUsername.Text && b.Password == txt_Password.Text)
                    select b;
        if (login.Count()==1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            main frmmain = new main();
            frmmain.Show();
        }
        var query = db.Tbl_Users.Where(c => c.Username == txtUsername.Text).Single();
        UserNameLogedIn = query.Name.ToString();

    }
```